# How to target form input fields whose names are changing everytime after reloading page in iMacros?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, imacros

I have been trying to target a form on a site but guess what I realized after playing my iMacros script again and again after recording more than 5 times..that the form name and input name is changing everytime the page reloads..also there is no other attribute through which I can target that using HTML and neither do X/Y Position Recording Mode is helping...so if you people let me know please..How to make it work?

Here is the form code which I am trying to target but since it's changing everytime so how it can be done please :

```
<form action="" method="post">
<div class="uzuyjgec">
<input name="kAEuwLjmplRMZazfl/s9bW6YpnOxDDX2/2K0sobG" class="tbox" type="text">
</div>
<div class="tyqtmvha">
<input name="kwHKrLjmplTDzY/lMx57neltV9ErW378S1mX9h5S" class="tbox" type="text">
</div>
<input name="submit" value="Search!" class="tbox" type="submit">
</form>
```

I just took out the code for the inputs but it's so confusing there are so much inputs in the code...!

Here is full original code in live state : http://jsfiddle.net/rt1ff6ab/

It's showing as too many inputs in live state in jsfiddle but it's showing only 2 inputs in the site here it screenshot please as :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/451QH.png

Comment: What do you mean by "target a form"? Why do you have the form and input names changing? What are you trying to target the form with?

Comment: I want to automate the search process so that I can use iMacros script to do that but since the names of the inputs are changing it's really going hard for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the JSFiddle and the image you showed, it looks like some of the inputs are hidden. You can use this code to grab the visible inputs:

```
var isVisible=function(node){
    return (node.offsetWidth && node.offSetWidth >0) || (node.offsetHeight && node.offsetHeight>0);
};
var inputs=[].filter.call(document.querySelectorAll('input'),isVisible);
var usernameInput=inputs[0];
var hoursInput=inputs[1];

console.log(usernameInput,hoursInput);
```

The code logs the first and second visible inputs on the page to the console.

I forked your JSFiddle and added CSS to hide all but two of the inputs: http://jsfiddle.net/28k59uhj/2/

UPDATE:

It's hard for me to know how to find exactly the elements you are looking for without playing with the actual page. Here's another try:

```
var isCandidateRegion=function(node){
    return (node.innerText.indexOf('Username')>-1 && node.innerText.indexOf('Hours')>-1);
};
//Find the last table in th document that contains 'Username' and 'Hours'
var candidateRegions=[].filter.call(document.querySelectorAll('table'),isCandidateRegion);
var targetRegion=candidateRegions[candidateRegions.length-1];

var isVisible=function(node){
    return (node.offsetWidth && node.offSetWidth >0) || (node.offsetHeight && node.offsetHeight>0);
};
var inputs=[].filter.call(targetRegion.querySelectorAll('input'),isVisible);
var usernameInput=inputs[0];
var hoursInput=inputs[1];

console.log(usernameInput,hoursInput);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/28k59uhj/3/

Comment: Thanks..but since there are too much forms with inputs visible on that page..so how can I get only these ones please..!

Comment: Awesome! Can you mark my answer as correct? Glad I could help.

Comment: Sure..! I am going to do that..!

Answer (score 0):

you could get it like this if there is only one form with 2 inputs, or you could do document.form[0]

```js
var inputs=document.getElementsByTagName('input');
inputs[0].value="username";
inputs[1].value="password";
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text"/> 
  <input type="text"/>
  </form>
```

Comment: it's really going difficult for me...there are too much input fields and two of them are only working the rest are kept hidden through CSS display and visibility code...! so then any possibilities?

Comment: But since the div names are also changing everytime so it's difficult..!

Comment: You're not going by div or class names, you're going by html tag names. I 've given you 2 ways to get the elements, modify the code above for your needs.